# Replicate bug: The certificate for this server is invalid

Tags: ios, ssl, certificate, afnetworking

Some of my users have been experiencing the following error:

> The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be "DOMAIN NAME" which could put your confidential information at risk

[image]

In what ways **can I** reproduce this bug? Is it possible to do it using Charles?
*It's important to note that I don't want to fix it, just reproduce it.
*

I am using `AFNetworking`

I tried changing the time of the simulator and removing https from some urls but I couldn't reproduce the message.

Comment: It could be that everything is working just like it should. That error could be caused by an access point that trying to TLS interception (aka MITM), perhaps for legitimate(ish) reasons or perhaps for malicious reasons. How to reproduce it? Have your users tell *where* they were when that happened and go to one of those places and see if it happens to you. This question is, I think, better asked on [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/), provided you make clear you are interested about what in mobile networking environment could be causing the error.